# Circle a region in Folium keeps changing

Tags: jupyter-notebook, folium, jupyterhub

I am trying circle a region that is 1km from the centre of the CBD of Melbourne. Please see the code that i put in, as I zoom out the map, the circle is not changing accordingly to scale. Please help me out and see that problem.

Will I need to use geo.json? Please advice. Thank you so much. Your help will be appricated!

```
map_distance_vs_price = folium.Map(location=[-37.81, 144.96],
                    tiles = "Stamen Terrain",
                    zoom_start = 12)

folium.CircleMarker([-37.81, 144.96],
                    radius=100,
                    popup='Price:',
                    color='#3186cc',
                    fill_color='#3186cc',
                   ).add_to(map_distance_vs_price)
```

[map image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ankgZ.png)

[map image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tymYh.png)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `Circle` instead. The docstring for `CircleMarker` mentions this

> radius: int
>       The radius of the circle in pixels.
>       **For setting the radius in meter, use Circle.**

Comment: Thanks Bob! That fixed my problem!